# Complex Grouping, Sorting and Value filtering in Pandas

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, sorting

Have a pandas dataframe in the following form:

```
Col1  Col2   Col3   

 t1       m1   1

 t2     m2   7   

 t3     m1   4

 t4     m2   8

 t5     m3   4

 t6     m3   6

 t7     m3   11

 t8     m4    9
```

I want to create to labels ( say hi/low/med) into a new column based on the following:
 Group the data based on Col2 and then sort the data (assuming asscending) based on Col1. Once done then we will choose the

first match of the sorted data (the lowest value) within a group and check the following:

If the first value of Col3  within a group >x :

```
 if any of values in the remaining group  <=x : 

    Then assign high for the first match to Col 4      #a1

 else 

    assign med for the first match  to Col4          #a2
```

If the first value of Col 3 within a group <=x and any of values in the

remaining group  < or >=x :

```
  Then assign low for the first match to Col 4        #b1
```

Also if there is only one element in a group ( as in the case m4 below), then we assign a value high/low based on value >or

At the end drop the rmeaining elements of each groups excpet the first one.

Thus assuming x = 4 and assuming (t1

```
 Col1  Col2 Col3   Col4

 t1     m1   1      low

 t2     m2   7      med 

 t3     m1   4                    # should drop

 t4     m2   8                   # should drop  

 t5     m3   5      high  

 t6     m3   2                        # should drop 

 t7     m3   11                        # should drop

 t8     m4    9     high


 So final table will be like:

Col1  Col2 Col3   Col4 

 t1     m1   1      low

 t2     m2   7      med 

 t5     m3   5      high 

 t8     m4    9     high
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own yet? You should work through your logic and attempt a solution. No one will just provide you a straight up solution here.

Comment: Yes I have tried to groupby and sort the datafarme using df.sorted_values(df['col1', 'col2'], ascending = True).groupby('Col2'). But have not getting the correct data yet. Next step is to compare the rows..

Comment: Your first group will not meet any of the criteria you have set. The numbers passed for `Col3` in the first group will be `1` and `4`. Since `1` is less than your test value for `x` (note, your example is `x = 4`), then it cannot return `high` or `med`. It also cannot return `low` because the other value in the first group is `4`, and your check for `low` is only triggered if any of the remaining values are > or < than your `x` value, which is `4`, so they are equal! Long story short, your logic is very unclear and can be simplified. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Actually the first thing, where I am stuck is to create a function which can find me the first value of each group based on the minimum Col1 value. I am not getting how to make it.

Comment: `df.sort_values(['Col2','Col1']).groupby('Col2')['Col3'].apply(my_function, (4))`, where `4` is your `x` value. Then define your function that contains your associated logic.

Comment: Thanks Rahlf. Yes you were correct. I included the = for the second condition, so that I get a low.

Comment: Note that `< or >=` simply means "less than or greater than or equal to", which is literally any number....so why have that condition at all?

Comment: Thanks again. So once  create a function and have the data frame as you mentioned, how will I assign that data frame to Col 4? Also the syntax you have ( my_function, (4)), how will I use it?. My function is going to check the smallest value of the Col1 within a group and then put the if condition on the Col3 values  and then assign the states depending on the if conditions.. So if you please provide a short example, that will be helpful and I will appreciate. I am not very expert in programming !

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right... However, in that case we can assign low whenever the first match within a group ( based on the lowest col1 value) is <=x.

Comment: I dived into it and thought about the following algorithm(pseudocode) and need to implement it using pandas:

 
 I am finding the dataframes of min col1 by the following:
    A1 = df.loc[df.groupby("Col2")["Col1"].idxmin()] and 
 
 So the main task next will be to create a criterion as to check the 
 Col3  values in the dataframe A1  group (which we will keep) and the thing now 
 is to compare the values of the frame A1 >x x based on the resyt of the dataframe which is left.
 
 This is the part I am not able to get.

Comment: See my posted answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, take this sample dataframe (you have conflicting ones in your OP):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([
['t1',     'm1',   1],
['t2',     'm2',   7], 
['t3',     'm1',   4],
['t4',     'm2',   8],
['t5',     'm3',   5],
['t6',     'm3',   2],
['t7',     'm3',   11],
['t8',     'm4',    9]],
columns=['Col1',  'Col2',   'Col3'])
```

Yields:

```
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0   t1   m1     1
1   t2   m2     7
2   t3   m1     4
3   t4   m2     8
4   t5   m3     5
5   t6   m3     2
6   t7   m3    11
7   t8   m4     9
```

Then define your function with your logic:

```
def my_function(x, val):

    if x.shape[0]==1:
        if x.iloc[0]>val:
            return 'high'
        else:
            return 'low'

    if x.iloc[0]>val and any(i<=val for i in x.iloc[1:]):
        return 'high'
    elif x.iloc[0]>val:
        return 'med'
    elif x.iloc[0]<=val:
        return 'low'
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Now apply that function to your sorted and grouped dataframe, using `4` as your sample input for `x` as stated in your OP:

```
df['Col4'] = df.sort_values(['Col2','Col1']).groupby('Col2')['Col3'].transform(my_function, (4))

df = df.sort_values(['Col2','Col1']).groupby('Col2').first().reset_index()
```

This yields:

```
  Col2 Col1  Col3  Col4
0   m1   t1     1   low
1   m2   t2     7   med
2   m3   t5     5  high
3   m4   t8     9  high
```

Comment: awesome and brilliant. You saved me!

Comment: Great! If this answer helped, would appreciate the upvote and you can accept my answer by pressing the green check mark!

Comment: Yes I did that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Rahlf,if I may ask you, now if I want to make the val in the function dynamic in the sense that it gets the input from another column (say Column 0), how can I modify my_function?

Comment: Another issue is cropping up, getting the following issue:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Hi Stan, I think it would be best to pose that as a separate question and I (or someone else on SO) can help you with it. It's not a straightforward answer suited for a comment.

Comment: Rahlf, as you have helped me a lot already, I will request some more. In case we do not want to remove the second occurences in a group but rather assign a value different from the first occurence, how can we implement that?

Comment: You can simply add that logic inside of the `my_function` function in my answer. If you print the result of only the first line of my answer above, you will see that a value is returned for each row in each group. The `first()` method in the second line of my answer is what restricts the final output to the first row in each group.

Comment: Yes so right now the my_function you created returns a value for all rows in the group. However if I want to return a value for the first location and any other values for any row in the same group, will I need to create an array and dump those.. How will I make sure that first one in the group and the rest are getting different values, without  assigning a vector etc, is what I am stuck. Thanks

Comment: A quick and dirty solution would just be to add another if statement in `my_function` that checks the row index location in that respective group and handle it that way. Again, I would post this as another question to get a more comprehensive answer!

Comment: Ok I will do that. Thanks

Comment: Added te question to the link:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744334/creating-a-function-to-perform-grouping-and-sorting-based-on-columns-in-pandas-d