# Creating a function to perform grouping and sorting based on columns in Pandas dataframe and Labeling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([
[100,     'm1',   1, 4],
[200,     'm2',   7, 5], 
[120,     'm1',   4, 4],
[240,     'm2',   8, 5],
[300,     'm3',   5, 4],
[330,     'm3',   2, 4],
[350,     'm3',   11, 4],
[200,     'm4',    9, 4]],
columns=['Col1',  'Col2',   'Col3', 'Col4'])
```

I am wanting to group the data into two groups based on the Col2 group. However the first match should be assigned one value and the rest of the matches should be assigned a different value. Rahlf helped me to get 
a function created

```
def my_function(x, val):

    if x.shape[0]==1:
        if x.iloc[0]>val:
            return 'high'
        else:
            return 'low'

    if x.iloc[0]>val and any(i<=val for i in x.iloc[1:]):
        return 'high'
    elif x.iloc[0]>val:
        return 'med'
    elif x.iloc[0]<=val:
        return 'low'
    else:
        return np.nan
```

and then do

```
df['Col5'] = df.sort_values(['Col2','Col1']).groupby('Col2')['Col3'].transform(my_function, (4))
```

However, I need two modifications to the function. Instead of the val, it will take the corresponding value from the Col 4 and then return one value (like 'low' to the first match within a group (based on the sorted col1) and then say 'low_red' for the rest of the matches in the group.

So my question is how can I modify the function to do that?

My Input:

```
   Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4    
   100   m1     1     4    
   200   m2     7     5    
   120   m1     4     4   
   240   m2     8     5   
   300   m3     5     4   
   330   m3     2     4    
   350   m3    11     4    
   200   m4     9     4
```

Expected Output:

```
   Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4   Col 5    
   100   m1     1     4    low    
   200   m2     7     5    med    
   120   m1     4     4    low_red    
   240   m2     8     5    med_red    
   300   m3     5     4    high    
   330   m3     2     4    high_red    
   350   m3    11     4    high_red    
   200   m4     9     4    high
```

Comment: You should include your expected output in your question as well, and it might be helpful to provide a link to your previous question for reference.

Comment: Added it in the  question. Thanks Rahlf

Comment: Does a division with 100 in the col1 implies the existence of red in your desired result?

Comment: I would wager not @JoPapou13, considering I worked on the first part of this question with the OP

Comment: Yes Rahlf is correct. There is no division involved. Just if the second occurrence within a sorted group has a specific value ( the criterion is in the function) then it is *_red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a higher level function (let's call it `my_function()`) that is called by `transform()`, which then calls a lower level function (let's call it `deeper_logic()`) that applies the previous logic outlined in your question, like so:

```
def my_function(group):

    val = df.iloc[group.index]['Col4']

    value = deeper_logic(group.iloc[0], val.iloc[0], group)

    return [value if i==0 else value + '_red' for i in range(group.shape[0])]

def deeper_logic(x, val, group):

    if group.shape[0]==1:
        if x>val:
            return 'high'
        else:
            return 'low'

    if x>val and any(i<=val for i in group.iloc[1:]):
        return 'high'
    elif x>val:
        return 'med'
    elif x<=val:
        return 'low'
    else:
        return np.nan

df['Col5'] = df.sort_values(['Col2','Col1']).groupby('Col2')['Col3'].transform(my_function)
```

This yields:

```
   Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4      Col5
0   100   m1     1     4       low
1   200   m2     7     5       med
2   120   m1     4     4   low_red
3   240   m2     8     5   med_red
4   300   m3     5     4      high
5   330   m3     2     4  high_red
6   350   m3    11     4  high_red
7   200   m4     9     4      high
```

Note that `transform()` operates on series and returns a like-indexed NDFrame, which is the result that we want (i.e. retain the index of the original dataframe). Therefore, we can call `transform()` with our `Col3` column, and then extract the corresponding `Col4` column values from the original index using `iloc` in the function being called from `transform()`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I will check and let you know and accept the answer.

Comment: Would appreciate your upvote as well! Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes that's the way it works!! I voted it.